# Why is my counter number not updating using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

the counter number is not updating even after clicking the button.

```js
var counterNumber = 0;
var counterText = document.querySelector("strong");
var reduceButton = document.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
var increaseButton = document.querySelectorAll("button")[1];


increaseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  counterNumber++;
})

reduceButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  counterNumber--;
})

counterText.textContent = counterNumber;
```

Comment: Can you edit sample HTML into the code snippet?

Comment: `counterText.textContent = counterNumber;` should be inside each listener callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your eventListener acts on the button clicks and counterNumber are increased as it should (you can add a console.log to see this) But you never assign the new value to your text counterText. That row is run once and not everytime you click a button.

Move this row:

```
counterText.textContent = counterNumber;
```

to be within your eventListener functions